# Play Framework - Retrieve the client's IP when using TCP load balancing

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Use case: a Play application behind Amazon ELB which is configured for TCP load balancing.

Amazon ELB provides the client's connection information via [Proxy Protocol 1](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.5/doc/proxy-protocol.txt).

How to retrieve this information in Play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have turned on proxy protocol support, it adds haproxy's proprietary proxy protocol header as the first thing sent in the TCP request.  Effectively, it adds the following line *before* the http request:

```
PROXY TCP4 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.11 56324 443
```

This is not valid HTTP, so Play does not support it, if Play receives a request like this, it will simply return an error.

What you can do is install a proxy on your EC2 node that does support proxy protocol, and then have that add the proxy protocol ip address into the X-Forwarded-For header to the Play app. Instructions on how to configure nginx to support proxy protocol in this way can be found here:

https://chrislea.com/2014/03/20/using-proxy-protocol-nginx/

Comment: Is there any ETA on adding Proxy Protocol support as a feature in Play? Is this something that can be done inside Play itself or does it require modification in an external library? Thanks.

Comment: Play is built on Netty, and Netty does have a proxy protocol handle that can be added.  It could be provided as a configuration option.  There are no plans to implement this, if it does happen it will be a pull request from the community.  Also, Play 3 is moving to akka-http (aka spray), which doesn't have proxy protocol support.  The feature request for that is here: https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/846

Comment: Is Proxy Protocol supported in Play 2.5 or Play 2.6 version ?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve any HTTP header from the request. If the proxy information is available in a HTTP header (I'm not familiar with Amazon ELB and what HTTP header it uses, but I'm assuming it would use a HTTP header of sorts) you could parse it yourself, like so:

```
val maybeClientIp: Option[String] = request.headers.get("PROXY").flatMap { header =>
  val proxyProtocolHeader = header.split(" ")
  if (proxyProtocolHeader.length > 2) {
    Some(proxyProtocolHeader(2))
  } else {
    None
  }
}
```

Comment: X-Forwarded-For is not available if TCP load balancing is used

Comment: Right, I read too fast. Do you actually get any kind of HTTP header with the encoded proxy header? It looks like once you have the header you could parse it yourself

Comment: ELB prepends a header to the TCP data. So the real question is how to retrieve it.